# Worshipping Lord Sharabha in Tantra

Tags: shiva, worship, agamas, tantra

According to Shiva Puran, Lord Shiva had to take avatar of Sharabha to stop Lord Narasimha from destroying whole universe out of anger after killing Hiranyakshipu.

His power is intolerable for a simple Sadhaka. So I want to know how to worship Lord Sharabha in Tantra way properly ?

Comment: How are so u sure that he is worshipped in the Tantric way? I can't remember reading anything. Did u get some hint from some websites or books?

Comment: @Rickross Have a look : https://archive.org/details/ShriSharabhShaluvrajTantraPrayogaToDestroyTheEnemyGodShiva  Read the title of the book.

Comment: Okay but the books that I follow do not have much (or anything rather) about his worship.

Comment: Which books you follow ? Why do you think it has to be in your books only ? @Rickross Please ping me on Agama chatroom.

Comment: I follow the best books on Tantras like Brihat Tantrasara, Shaktananda Tarangini, Nityotsava etc etc.. I don't think that it has to be in those books only. But they are the important and the more  well known books on the Tantras.

Comment: @Rickross please add me to agama chatroom too, please.

Comment: @Shashwat there you go: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a noteworthy diety in shakta and shaiva tantric traditions. Also usually known by names like Sri Sharabheshwara or Sri Pakshiraaj.  less audience is aware of such deities. It is also linked with other fierce deities like pratyangira and others.

Mainly it is considered best for protection and to get rid of possible preta and related problems.

[Akasha bhairava kalpa](https://www.scribd.com/doc/266110285/Akash-Bhairava-Kalpam-Kaviraj-Pt-Nanak-Chand-Sharma#) has some sections dedicated to him and other similar deities hence it can be followed.

Along with that there is also [sharabha kalpa](https://archive.org/details/Sharabha-kalpam--) which can is available online. Also there is [sharabha tantram](https://www.scribd.com/doc/111710494/Sharabh-Tantram-Compiled-From-Akash-Bhairava-Kalpam-By-Datia-Swami).

So authentic upasana should be done in accordance with above manuals.

Appearance of [Sharabha](https://dharmamarg.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/sharabha/)

> The Sharaba form of Shiva was the structural blend of human, animal
>   and bird with gigantic as well as blistering look. It had so many
>   hands, claws and legs, and almost resembled a huge dragon. The
>   entangled tresses in the body highlighted the ferocity of the
>   structure to a greater extend. In the head there was a massive crest
>   which looked like a dome. There were well spread wings on the back
>   side of the body with a long tail. The extremely sharp incisors in the
>   mouth and inflexible claws were its main weapons. Its thunder like
>   voice created echo in the environments and was horrible to hear. It
>   had three eyes which were glowing like fire balls. Its teeth and lips
>   were well formed and can be seen properly. It produced awful hissing
>   sounds throughout.
>
> Shiva Purana describes Sharabha as thousand-armed, lion-faced and with
>   matted hair, wings and eight feet. Sharabha Upanishad portrays
>   Sharabha with two heads, two wings, eight legs of the lion with sharp
>   claws and a long tail. Kalika Purana describes Sharabha as black in
>   colour, with four feet downwards and four feet uplifted, with an
>   enormous body. It also has a long face and nose, nails, eight legs,
>   eight tusks, a cluster of manes, and a long tail. It jumps high
>   repeatedly making a loud cry. At first Lord Shiva send Veerabhadra and
>   asked Narasimha to cool down. But Narasimha ignored his appeal. So he
>   created Sarabha which outclassed Narasimha both in structure and
>   power. Then Sarabha lifted Narasimha with its long tail and was about
>   to throw him. Narasimha realized this and prayed Sarabha to forgive
>   him. This made Lord Siva to aware the recovery of Vishnu from
>   ferocious nature and hence did not hurt him. As a mark of respect to
>   Lord Siva, Narasimha removed the skin of lion from his body and
>   presented to Sharabeshwaramurti. Thus the incarnation as Sarabha by
>   Lord Siva pacified the Narasimha manifestation of Lord Vishnu. This
>   embodiment of Siva is referred as Sarabeshawara. In Shiva temples
>   idols of two Sarabeshwara are found at the entrance of sanctum.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other references that can be looked into for the worship of Sharabha.
1) [Pakshiraj Archananam](https://archive.org/details/PakshirajArchanamYogeshMishra)
2) [Sharabh Sahasranaama 1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/sharabhasahasra.pdf)
3) [Sharabh Sahasranaama 2](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/sharabhasahasranAmastotra.pdf)
4) [Sharabh Sahasranaama 3](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/sharabhasahasranAmastotra3.pdf)